# Hindi characters as ???? in PDF/A

Tags: pdf-generation

I am converting html templates into PDF/A format using jod converter3(using open office 3x).This is working fine in the development environment(using Eclipse and JRE).
But while executing the same program on production(Linux,JBoss 5) some templates that have hindi characters in output pdf with ??? 
Working fine for english characters

Tried running my program via command line w/o app server still the same output.

java -cp bin:PATH/JARNAME.jar:lib ConvertToPDFA encoding=UTF8 x (Not working).

HTML is also UTF-8 encoded.

Please suggest the problem area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for a hindi font tiff under the location usr\share\fonts\TTF.
if missing then create the same and place the required font tiff.